# implement mapview version 1 inside fragment?

Tags: android, android-mapview, fragment

Is there a way to implement mapview version 1 inside fragment?
I tried sth like:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);                

    }
```

Then, I want 2 fragments . One that has the mapview and second which will have a textview in which the location will be  shown.

I can't implement the first fragment.I can't figure how to implement the map.I mean , for the mapview to work it needs "extends MapActivity" but I need "extends fragment".

Also , in main.xml how to do it?I tried :

```
 <fragment 
        class="com.google.android.maps.MapView"
        android:name="com.example.....MapClass"  //is this right?but it is necessary for fragment?
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:apiKey="mykey" />
    <fragment 
        class="com.example...getloclass"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview, you can see that

> Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API as been officially deprecated
>   as of December 3rd, 2012

So you shouldn't use `MapView` anymore. I suggest  you use a `MapFragment` instead. See the excellent documentation for it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment